# nicematrix package: diagonal dotted lines (ddots) don't match

Tags: matrices, nicematrix

I was trying to make the following matrix with the `nicematrix` package:

```
\begin{equation*}
    A_c+B_c K_c=\begin{bNiceMatrix}
        0               & 1                     & 0         & \Cdots    & 0     \\
        \Vdots          & \Ddots                & \Ddots    & \Ddots    & \Vdots\\
                        &                       & \Ddots    & \Ddots    & 0     \\
        0               & \Cdots                &           & 0         & 1     \\
        -\alpha_n+k_n   & -\alpha_{n-1}+k_{n-1} & \Cdots    &           & -\alpha_1+k_1
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

The problem is that the diagonal dots don't go where I would like them to go:

[image]

I found out that the `nicematrix` package draws all the diagonal dotted lines parallel to the first one. The `nicematrix` [documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf) says to set to `false` the option `parallelize-diags` (page 23), but the compiler gives this error:

*Package keyvalue Error: Unknown option 'parallelize-diags' for package (keyvalue) nicematrix.*

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously, the key `parallelize-diags` was available only in `\NiceMatrixOptions`. In recent versions of `nicematrix`, it's also available for an individual environment.

Moreover, there is in your code two redundant commands `\Ddots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    A_c+B_c K_c=\begin{bNiceMatrix}[parallelize-diags=false]
        0               & 1                     & 0         & \Cdots    & 0     \\
        \Vdots          & \Ddots                & \Ddots    & \Ddots    & \Vdots\\
                        &                       &           &           & 0     \\
        0               & \Cdots                &           & 0         & 1     \\
        -\alpha_n+k_n   & -\alpha_{n-1}+k_{n-1} & \Cdots    &           & -\alpha_1+k_1
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]